# How to show Data in UITableView which getting its data from 2 different API

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsurl, dispatch-async

In my project I am showing data in `UItableView` from calling some API, my tableView contains imageView, and for its I am getting Image URL.

I have made 2 async calls:

1) For fetching all Data from api which also contains img URL

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler:
    {
    (data,response,error) -> Void in

    if error == nil && data != nil
    {
        do
        {
        let data1 = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                // Here calling protocol and reloading UItable View
                self.userInfoDelegate?.setUserInfo(data1)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Something Went Wrong in REST")

        }
    }

}).resume()
```

Till here I am populating UITableView's required text. Now I need that `ImageView` inside Table should also show images from imagUrl From first API

I am making another async call for fetching images for URL

```
func setUserInfo(data : NSMutableArray) {
    var indexOf = 0

    self.userTableView.reloadData()
    for item  in data
    {
        imageFromUrl(indexOf,urlString: to_pic,name:name )
        indexOf = indexOf + 1

    }

}
```

Here is code from which I am getting NSData of images and storing image on UITableView when it get data

```
func imageFromUrl(index : Int,urlString: String,name : String)
{
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let imgData = data
            {
                var image = UIImage?()
                image = UIImage(data: imgData)
                self.placeImage  = image

            }

            if(self.placeImage == nil)
            {
                self.placeImage  = UIImage(named: "User-2")
            }

            self.imageDictionary[index] = ["id":index,"image":self.placeImage!]
            // ANother Asynch
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                if(self.imageDictionary.count == self.userArray.count)
                {
                    for var newIndex in 0...self.imageDictionary.count - 1
                    {
                        self.setImageOnTableWithIndex(newIndex)
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // do whatever you need with the task e.g. run
        task.resume()
    }
}

func setImageOnTableWithIndex(index : Int)
{
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)

    let cell = userTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UserListTableViewCell;

    cell.userImageView.image = self.imageDictionary[index]!["image"] as? UIImage
}
```

It sometimes shows image Properly but most of time get crash on random line. I know I have to properly deal with many async call but not able to find proper way.

Comment: you can call anther Api after getting a response of first api and hold that data in one array

Comment: Instead of downloading image this way use `SDWebImage`. Also it is work in Lazy loader manner, so no need to download all the image at a same time, instead it will download image that is currently displaying on screen.

Comment: Getting crashes on *random* lines?  Are you sure this isn't bad hardware?

Comment: no it is something with multiple asyc call

Answer (score 1):

You can user SDWebImage to download the image asynchronously and display in UIImageView. Find the source in following link

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

There are various libraries available to download images asynchronously :

- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
- [Fast Image Cache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache)
- [King Fisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)